# chi square test / grubbs analysis

Tags: r, input, outliers, chi-squared

Basically I want to do a chi square test on a file called `output9.csv`. There are two columns in the file, I want to pick one of them to do the grubbs analysis on.

1) How do I read the output.

This is what I have so far:

```
d <- read.csv('data.csv')
```

So for this part, what should be inside my bracket, i.e. `output9.csv`?

```
chisq.(mydata)
```

Comment: if you assign your data as `dd`, then what is `mydata`,  `data` and `data$col2`?

Comment: @sotos oh sorry I screwed this up, I'll start over. I guess I just want a variable name for my output9.csv. Can you please writen an answer? I want know how to do a chi square test?

Comment: You should give more information though, plus a reproducible example (use `dput`). Your question as it is could be closed as too broad or  off-topic. Also have a look at `?chisq.test`

Comment: @soto, hey soto all this I have right now:

Comment: @soto: d <- read.csv('data.csv')
bytes <- d$Bytes

library(outliers)

Comment: so basically you want to test `bytes` for outliers? From the documentation of `chisq.out.test` you can just use `chisq.out.test(bytes, variance = var(bytes))`. Did you try that?

Comment: @sotos can you please write an answer? I will be trying a bit, since my R studio crashed and I'm reinstalling now. I proomise will accept your answer.

Comment: @soto also sir for the opposite outlier, do I just simply like this chisq.out.test(chisq.out.test(bytes, variance = var(bytes)), opposite = true)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `chisq.out.test`, you can utilize it to find the **one** outlier of your data considering that you also give the variance. By default, `chisq.out.test` finds the value with the largest difference from the mean. If the parameter `opposite` is set to `TRUE` then the test will go ahead and find the lowest one.

```
library(outliers)
d <- read.csv('data.csv')
test1 <- chisq.out.test(d$Bytes, variance = var(d$Bytes))

#or for opposite

test2 <- chisq.out.test(d$Bytes, variance = var(d$Bytes), opposite = TRUE)
```